# Is asking about Maya or 3DS MAX Blender.. API on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I understand that using apps is not on topic but is asking question about programming in these environments on topic? I mean is programming with Maya, 3DS MAX, Blender, Modo etc.

If it is on topic, or partially on topic what kinds of restrictions do we expect to have to follow? Certainly doing QT GUI's for maya is off topic is it not, whereas making a shader, manipulating the renderer implementing a new shape or so might be on topic.

Comment: Déjà Vu, See http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/19071/should-this-site-accept-tools-specific-questions

Answer (score 7):

If I got the *vibe* of the Area51 proposal that I thought I did, this stack is for computer graphics **theory**, **research**, **programming**, **implementation**, and anything similar to such focuses.

As such, there would be quite a bit of overlap if it included app-specific *modeling* questions in general.

---

As far as scripting environments within specific modeling applications, ask yourself some of these:

- Does the question pertain to how a fundamental computer graphics concept works? **OK**
- Does the question pertain to how a specific function of a modeling application works? **NOT OK**
- Does the question pertain to why a visual defect is occurring *from suspect code*? **OK**
- Does the question pertain to why a visual defect is occurring *due to a potential bug in a modeling application*? **NOT OK**
- Does the question ask about lighting concepts, lighting-related shader code, lighting defects from resulting code, etc? **OK**
- Does the question ask about modeling app-specific lighting questions - more specifically, questions pertaining to "light" entities within an application? **NOT OK**

But most importantly

- Does the question pertain to a problem that can transcend a specific modeling app?

*These* are the types of questions I've been asking myself when reviewing these first posts on this stack.

Comment: Questions that are specific to the usage of a particular application can be migrated to [SU], if the quality is high enough. SU has a [Maya tag](http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/maya). Blender even has [it's own SE site](http://blender.stackexchange.com).